# How to disable all links before load jQuery?

Tags: javascript

I need a pure Javascript code to disable all links while loading the page, avoiding to click them and redirecting to other page when its using a [Facebox](http://defunkt.io/facebox/).

Can be something that I place in a `<script>` tag in the `<head>`.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

Ok, I get that in `head` doesn't work. But in `body` ending work properly. That's why I asked for suggestions. :)

Comment: Do you just need a script to work on `A:href` element's *before* `$(document).ready()` (or `$(document).load()`) runs?

Comment: I think a pure javascript in head will block all links faster then a eventually user click. Thats what I need for now. Waits for jQuery loading appears unnecessarily slow for me.

Comment: Without an event to load it, it will run immediately as the page loads (top to bottom).

Comment: It can be a problem? Because @alex alternative works fine in FF.

Comment: It's *in the `HEAD`* that doesn't make sense. Read his answer again.

Comment: Well... both answers worked for me, so I'll wait the opinions and votes before setting a correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`document.links`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.links) and prevent their default behaviour with [`preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.preventDefault).

```
var links = document.links;
for (var i = 0, length = links.length; i < length; i++) {
    links[i].onclick = function(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

If you wanted a more permanent disabling of the links, use `removeAttribute('href')`.

Place this code somewhere after the closing `body` tag if you don't want to use `DOMContentLoaded` or the `window` `load` event.

You can't place it in the `head` element otherwise and have it execute immediately because `document.links` will most certainly be empty.

Comment: Because that's the question? Ah! Recursion!

Comment: Note that this would have to go at the end of the page (just before body tag) but before the jQuery inclusion. Otherwise links.length ==0

Comment: Nice! Exactly what I needed at this time. Thx @alex

Comment: But as per Hamish's comment the question said "disable all links while loading the page", and this only works once the page is at least parsed (even if some images are still loading or whatever).

Answer (score 3):

Make this the first script tag in your head section:

```
window.onclick = function(e) {
    if(typeof $ === 'undefined') {
            e = e || window.event;
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

This catches all click events, and if `$` is undefined, cancels the event.

Has the advantage of working even before the DOM is loaded.

Comment: In some cases (as I tested) this script doesn't work in `head`. But as you said before, @alex script work in `body` ending. So thx anyway.

Comment: @Edison: works for me in the `<head>`, can you elaborate on the issues?

Comment: Might be that it doesn't work properly in IE. Seems to attach things in a slightly different order.

Comment: I found the code above also blocks out `input type="file"` selections. Is there a simple way to exclude those?

Answer (score 0):

In the page, give all your links empty *href* values. Use the load event to assign appropriate values. Users with javascript disabled or unavailable will see broken links.