# Disable all target="_blank" links on page

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, preventdefault

I'm building content for a site that is displayed through an iframe in a PhoneGap mobile app. The content is pulled from a CMS that also serves the content for the main website so it has a mix of internal and target="_blank" links.

Handling target="_blank" links is proving problematic in PhoneGap so I want to disable them in the app website without touching the content because it's also used on the main website.

What I need is jQuery that runs on page load, finds all links with target="_blank" attribute and makes links normal text.

Something like this ([How to disable all links before load jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7910628/how-to-disable-all-links-before-load-jquery)) disables all links but I only want to disable links that have target="_blank" attribute, and I want to hide the fact that the words were links in the first place:

```
var links = document.links;
for (var i = 0, length = links.length; i < length; i++) {
    links[i].onclick = function(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

So I don't want to simply preventDefault() on link click but remove the links completely while keeping the link text, and I want to apply this to target="_blank" links only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('a[target="_blank"]').each(function(){
   $(this).removeAttr('href');
});
```

Or if you want to completely remove `a` tags

```
$('a[target="_blank"]').each(function(){
   $(this).replaceWith($(this).text());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/kZqFD/

Comment: Not sure but seems like OP wants: $(this).removeAttr('target');

Comment: Actually accepting this answer because it's marginally cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the links and replace them with text only doing this:

```
$('a[target="_blank"]').each(function(){
    var linkText = $(this).text();
    $(this).after(linkText);
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hXFse/

Comment: +1 for being the only one to read the question and do what has been asked.

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
$('a[target=_blank]')
```

is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Convert `<a>` with `target='_blank'` to behave as normal text.

```
 $("a[target='_blank']").removeAttr("href");
```

or to remove `<a>` with a `<span>`

```
$.each($('a[target="_blank"]'),function(){
var value = $(this).text();
$(this).replaceWith('<span>'+value+'</span>');
});
```